# How to run unit-tests present in a static library using CMake, by linking the static library to an UWP test app?

Tags: unit-testing, cmake, uwp

## CMake and UWP:

I have cmaked a static library which contains unit-test cases, say Tests_Lib.lib

How can I link this static library, in any UWP test app say Test_UWP_App.
This app has no code reference to static library, so when I link to this library using cmake function target_link_libraries(Test_UWP_App Tests_Lib), it doesn't get loaded during runtime. How can I force the library to be loaded with the App, so that its test-cases can also be run.

On Mac/iOS platform, we can do this by target_link_libraries(Test_UWP_App -force_load Tests_Lib), but "-force_load" is Xcode specific compiler flag.

How can we do this for UWP in Visual Studio.